# Vue bootstrap datetimepicker style issues

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

When you hover from one day to the next day sometimes a resize is happening because I am using a border and the `td` sizes are different.Is it possible to resize each td for days to have an x for width and y for height?

In the end, I don't want to see any resizes when I hover from one day to another but I want to keep the border.

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackBlade/d7zpca1k/5/)

and I used this [component](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: Use [outline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) instead of `border` that's causing your resizing.

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks.